# GIT-SVN Issue on Mac

Tags: perl, git-svn, macos

I am in the process of getting git-svn working on my Mac.  I am currently on Lion (but I had similar results when testing on Snow Leopard.  I seem to be one of the few people having this issue.  This is different from the issue I see that some people had with just including  SVN/Core.pm.

Below is an attempt to do a git svn clone on a vanille repository (obviously the host and directory details have been changed for posting):

```
Macbook-Pro:git david$ git svn clone https://somesite.com/SVN/someRepo/
Initialized empty Git repository in /Projects/git/MyWorkspace/.git/
Can't load '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle' for module SVN::_Core: dlopen(/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
Referenced from: /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle
Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 204.    
at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 58.
```

Comment: It looks like the svn libraries are failing to load - does normal `svn checkout` work on your computer? How did you install git?

Comment: svn works fine via command line, but it seems the perl bindings for svn are screwed up.  I am currently using the git included on Mac, but in the past I did use the OS X installer for git - http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, simply installing git via Macports solved my problem.  I believe this problem was probably caused by older installs (maybe the Mac OS X Git Installer).  If you are in this scenario, first install Macports:

http://www.macports.org/install.php

Then, once Macports is installed (with the correct version for your OS), then run:

```
sudo port install git-core +svn
```

After this, I just had to use the git at the new location installed by Macports:

```
/opt/local/bin/git
```

I modified my PATH variable so that this was the git used by default.

Comment: Works for me, but the `Macport` command took me 30 minutes to execute... That `Macport` is just crazy, I prefer `Homebrew` but it doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly-different approach to this problem (as I am running a beta of XCode 4.2 as well):

1. Install the [Collabnet Subversion package](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/). I downloaded the OSX 10.7 version as I am running Lion on my Mac.
2. Create a symlink of all /opt/subversion/libsvn_* files in /usr/lib/

Answer (score 0):

I spent a copious amount of time trying to get this fixed. None of the approaches above helped. What really fixed the issue was to **remove** the following line from my `~/.zshrc` (`.bash_profile`, if you use bash.)

```
export VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=yes;
```